# jquery exotic id selection

Tags: jquery, select

Does anyone know how to select with jeury an id with this form `1329456738.1053,name`?

Non working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zep6Y/

```
<div id="1329456738.1053,name">Some text</div>
<a href="#" class="publish_post" id="1329456738.1053">aaa</a>
```

```
$('#1329456738.1053,name').text()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid id....

Comment: @XyanEwing I believe, it is a valid ID in HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html - although I would try my best to 'normalize' them in my own apps

Comment: The problem is that the dot is used as a class selector making it look for a css class named `1053`. The comma makes it look for a tag named `name`.

Comment: @XyanEwing AFAIK, the only disallowed characters in ID attributes are space characters ([HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)). Though it's certainly not a very *sensible* ID...

Comment: @lonesomeday: Thanks for that link! I haven't been keeping up with the changes in HTML5, now I guess `id="1♥♦♣♠☠"` is valid...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just checked, works:

```
$('.publish_post').click (function(){                        
                        alert (this.id);    
                        alert ($('#1329456738\\.1053\\,name').text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be more consistent:

```
alert ($('[id="' + this.id + '"]').text());
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zep6Y/1/)